# How to convert a hexadecimal value into a signed integer in PHP?

Tags: php, hex

I am trying to convert a hex string into a signed integer.

I am able to easily transfer it into an unsigned value with hexdec() but this does not give a signed value.

Edit:

code in VB - the two "AA" hex values are representative.

```
Dim bs(2) As Byte
bs(1) = "AA"
bs(2) = "AA"
Dim s As Short
s = BitConverter.ToInt16(bs, 1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this [comment](http://www.php.net/manual/pl/function.hexdec.php#108897) via php.net:

> hexdec() returns unsigned integers. For example hexdec("FFFFFFFE") returns 4294967294, not -2. To convert to signed 32-bit integer you may do:

```
<?php
echo reset(unpack("l", pack("l", hexdec("FFFFFFFE"))));
?>
```

Comment: The type could be `q` ( `64-bit` ), instead of `l` ( `32-bit` ), to support `64-bit integer`. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php

Answer (score 3):

As said on the [hexdec manual page](http://php.net/hexdec) :

> The function can now convert values
>   that are to big for the platforms
>   integer type, it will return the value
>   as float instead in that case.

If you want to get some kind of big integer (not float), you'll need it stored inside a string... This might be possible using [BC Math](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) functions.

For instance, if you look in the comments of the hexdec manual page, you'll find [this note](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php#90309)

If you adapt that function a bit, to avoid a notice, you'll get :

```
function bchexdec($hex)
{
    $dec = 0;
    $len = strlen($hex);
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $len; $i++) {
        $dec = bcadd($dec, bcmul(strval(hexdec($hex[$i - 1])), bcpow('16', strval($len - $i))));
    }
    return $dec;
}
```

*(This function has be copied from the note I linked to ; and only a bit adapted by me)*

And using it on your number :

```
$h = 'D5CE3E462533364B';
$f = bchexdec($h);
var_dump($f);
```

The output will be :

```
string '15406319846273791563' (length=20)
```

So, not the kind of big float you had ; and seems OK with what you are expecting :

> Result from calc.exe =
>   15406319846273791563

Hope this help ;-)

*And, yes, user notes on the PHP documentation are sometimes a real gold mine ;-)*

Comment: This method did not handle the minus yet, in fortunately. Example: we expect `echo bchexdec('f8a14564c1d18e58')` to be `-531066982002225576` , but in fact it returns `17915677091707326040`

Answer (score 2):

I've been trying to find a decent answer to this question and so I wrote this function which works well for a Hex string input, returning a signed decimal value.

```
public function hex_to_signed_int($hex_str){
    $dec = hexdec($hex_str);
    //test is value negative
    if($dec & pow(16,strlen($hex_str))/2 ){ return $dec-pow(16,strlen($hex_str));}
    return $dec;
}
```