# Get negative numbers after conversion to float

Tags: php, hex, type-conversion

I have found a code which convert hexadecimal to floating numbers. My numbers are also negatives but after conversion I don't get it. Is it possible to convert from hex to float with negatives too? 
Code which I found:

```
function hexTo32Float($strHex) {
    $v = hexdec($strHex);
    $x = ($v & ((1 << 23) - 1)) + (1 << 23) * ($v >> 31 | 1);
    $exp = ($v >> 23 & 0xFF) - 127;
    return $x * pow(2, $exp - 23);
}
```

Number to test:
c57be300 -> 4030.1875 but should be negative -4030.1875.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/justinasr/PHPHexToFloat/blob/master/hextofloat.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a hexadecimal value into a signed integer in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12368811/1255289)